# Not able to get the Facebook page source code when trying and using with PHP cURL

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I tried to get the source code of the following Facebook page - https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=974372955923474&set=vb.213776828649761&type=2&theater. But it never returns the source code for the actual page, instead, it returns a source code which forms a 'Update your browser' page, it seems that I have used the wrong user-agent, but I changed the user agent to the newest version of Chrome and it still not working.

```
// Set curl option - following location - prevent redirects 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    // Set curl option - retransfer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Set curl option - no header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    // Set curl option - no body
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);

    // Set curl option - user agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"); // Necessary. The server checks for a valid User-Agent.

    // Execute CURL and get the response
    $curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: You are not supposed to scrape Facebook pages directly – in fact, their TOS forbid this, and of course they also have technical measures in place against this. Use the functionality their API provides instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to supply a login for this. I do not have a Facebook account logged on in my browser, and I need to logon. I do not see any logon information supplied in your PHP code. I think if you need to retrieve information or media from Facebook you need to have a look at the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right, the video is private, so we can't access any information of the video without logged in.